# Tomcat Not Finding JSP File

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am learning Java EE, so I started with JSP. I set up my eEclipse environment, and got a simple project running. When I attempt to run the project Tomcat cannot find my JSP file. I put my JSP file under the `WebContent` folder, but Tomcat still cannot find it.

[image: What It Looks Like]

I don't understand why it won't work. Do I place my files somewhere else? I left my `web.xml` at default:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Test</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: How do you deploy this application? Unless it is deployed under root context, you shall use web application (context) name as prefix in URL (before jsp). E.g. http://localhost:8080/application/test.jsp

Comment: I just used all the defaults, then hit run in eclipse that came up automatically

Comment: Try localhost:8080/Test/test.jsp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From screenshot you try to access to `http://localhost:8080/Test.jsp`, but I guess the application is reacheable on `/Test` path; so you have to access with:

`http://localhost:8080/Test/Test.jsp`

You can see and change this base path name on Eclipse from Project properties on tab `Web Project Settings -> Context root`.
Default value is project name.

Answer (score 0):

This `web.xml` will work fine if you run it as: htttp://localhost:8080//Test/test.jsp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Test</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>test.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.example.com:8080/Test/Test.jsp url means the project name is Test and Test.jsp is immediately after the project directory.